# Pegar o id de onde o max(valor) foi achado

Tags: mysql

Tentei assim, mas não esta vindo o valor correto

```
SELECT id, data, max(valor) 
FROM teste 
WHERE data BETWEEN '2017-03-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-04-01 00:00:00'
```

O valor de máximo vem perfeito, mas ele pega o primeiro id dentro dessa data.
Como pegar o id referente ao valor do max?
Se possível a data também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que desse jeito funciona, mas talvez haja uma solução melhor:

```
SELECT id, data, max(valor) 
FROM teste 
WHERE 
data BETWEEN '2017-03-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-04-01 00:00:00'
AND
valor in (select max(valor) FROM teste)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id,data,valor FROM teste WHERE 
data BETWEEN '2017-03-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-04-01 00:00:00'
ORDER BY valor DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Poderia explicar a query?

Comment: Ordena pelo maior valor em ordem decrescente, e pega apenas o primeiro resultado.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 id, data, valor
FROM teste 
WHERE data BETWEEN '2017-03-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-04-01 00:00:00' order by valor desc
```

Comment: Acho que isto apenas seria aplicável ao SQL Server, pessoalmente desconheço isto para MySQL. Por curiosidade tentei executar isto no MariaDB e resulta em "*You have an error in your SQL syntax*", seria uma mão-na-roda. :(

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar uma subquery ou utilizar um INNER JOIN.

Uma opção é usar o `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT id, 
       data,
       valor
FROM   teste 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(valor) AS valor 
                   FROM   teste 
                   WHERE  data BETWEEN '2017-03-01 00:00:00' AND 
                                       '2017-04-01 00:00:00') AS j 
       USING (valor)
```

O `INNER JOIN` irá pegar tudo que está entre as datas definidas e irá retornar o `max()`. Depois, utilizando o `Valor` como base (em `USING()`)  iremos pegar todos os dados que possuem o mesmo valor definido pelo `MAX()`.

---

Uma outra opção é simplesmente fazer um `valor = (SELECT ...)`, por exemplo:

```
SELECT id, 
       data, 
       valor 
FROM   teste 
WHERE  valor = (SELECT MAX(valor) 
                FROM   teste 
                WHERE  data BETWEEN '2017-03-01 00:00:00' AND 
                                    '2017-04-01 00:00:00')
```

Essa forma é mais fácil de compreender e executa o mesmo do que no outro método, primeiro pega o valor máximo (pelo `MAX()`) e então pega todas as informações onde o `valor` seja igual ao `MAX()`.